# Ubuntu container keep restarting

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

I'm using docker-compose to add a new ubuntu container but the container keeps restarting and I don't know why... any clue of what I can check ?

here my docker-compose service:

```
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: ubuntu
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /mnt:/NAS:rw
    environment:
      - TZ="Asia/Shanghai"
```

and here is the *docker ps* output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                            NAMES
6c084528838c        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"              6 minutes ago       Restarting (0) 18 seconds ago                                                    ubuntu
```

i'm using Docker 17.09 on Ubuntu server 17.04 and I'm running the container with this alias:

```
alias dcrun='docker-compose -f /home/docker-compose.yml'

dcrun up -d ubuntu
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you get anything in logs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is quite expected since you haven't defined any `command:` or `entrypoint:` in the docker compose.

Ubuntu image by default has `bash` command as `CMD` which isn't really a foreground process.
Ref - https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile

If you run it in interactive mode(-i), you will dive into `bash` automatically -

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu 
root@8d6ac0591d88:/#
```

Hence, once the `bash` command exits your container also dies but due to your `restart: unless-stopped` policy, Docker daemon keeps trying to restart it.

If you want your container to be up & running with compose, try defining  a foreground process as below -

```
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: ubuntu
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /mnt:/NAS:rw
    environment:
      - TZ="Asia/Shanghai"
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Your container will not restart now -

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                     NAMES
cee860adf641        ubuntu                             "tail -f /dev/null"      5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                                          ubuntu
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! :) Thanks. I used a Dockerfile with `CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]` at the end of the file to keep the container running.